# C++ вывод кириллицы из файла в консоль

Tags: c++, кодировка

Есть файл в кодировке `UTF-8` и при попытке напечатать полученное в консоли выводятся кракозябры вместо русских символов, при этом с английскими символами все отлично.

Comment: вот здесь в архиве есть пример чтения utf-8 файла и вывода на консоль: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2672106-page2.html#post14672876

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте еще раз кодировку файла. Если она действительно `UTF-8`, а не `CP-1251`, как любит делать блокнот в `ОС Windows`, то добавьте `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` в самый верх `int main`.

Comment: setlocale стоит `LC_ALL, "Russian"` и кодировка действительно UTF-8 (Использовал Notepad++)

Comment: Тогда крепите код в вопрос

Comment: Моя ошибка код с setlocale стоял после функции которая выполняла вывод в консоль, но проблема так и не решилась, нужно теперь использовать ANSI кодировку, а мне нужно UTF-8